# Lower ARIMA accuracy with BOX-COX

Tags: time-series, arima, data-transformation

I'm using ARIMA model for time series forecast. My data has increasing variance and I applied a BOX-COX transformation to stabilise it. Here are charts:
[image]

After I run my app it turned out that ARIMA produces slightly better accuracy for raw data:

- Raw data MAE error: 4.83
- BOX-COX transformed data MAE error: 4.97

As I understand ARIMA should produce better results for stationary data. Base on that I should see better accuracy when I'm using BOX-COX transformed data right?

I'm wondering why in my case model gives worst results for stationary data and what can I do to improve my model?

Comment: is this financial returns data?

Comment: Per @Taylor's comment, if these are financial returns, then explicitly modeling the variance through ARCH/GARCH is probably better. Also, [did you adjust for bias in back-transforming](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html)?

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa, ARCH/GRACH is one of models what I will definitely use. I just started learning about forecasting/ML and I'm curious why ARIMA with stationary data produces bigger error. I didn't adjust bias. THX for tip!

Comment: @Taylor, yes this is financial data.

Comment: looks like bitcoin or something. Sort of difficult to model the whole window because the scale process doesn't look stationary